# Outputting only the latter string with digits that sum the largest number in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

I've been struggling to code a function that returns only the latter string with digits that sum the largest number (in an array with phone numbers).

I've researched and have found some good tips about that issue. However, I still haven't managed to code it in the proper way, though.

The way the function is,  it returns all the numbers sorted and their scores, which is not wrong, though I need to print only the latter string with digits that sum the largest number.

Here comes my code block as a whole:

```js
function LargestPhoneNumber (array) { 
    
var phoneNumbers = array.map(function (m) {
    return {
        number: m,
        score: m.match(/\d/g).reduce(function (p, c) {
            return +p + +c;
        })
    };
})
phoneNumbers.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.score < b.score) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.score > b.score) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
});
console.log(phoneNumbers);

};
LargestPhoneNumber(['555-555-5555','111-111-1111','555-555-5456','222-121-2121']);
```

The function outputs:

```js
[ { number: '555-555-5456', score: 50 },
  { number: '555-555-5555', score: 50 },
  { number: '222-121-2121', score: 16 },
  { number: '111-111-1111', score: 10 } ]
```

Taking those inputs as example, even though there are two strings of digits equally large, the expected output should only be the latter: '555-555-5456'

I've tried looping too, with no success. I guess I've missed any point and I can not realize what it is.

Comment: You don't return from your function - if you add this, why don't you simply return `sums[0].number`

Comment: Where does this exercise come from? The *"largest phone number in array"* problem shows up here almost weekly

Comment: Great one! Thank you @mmm !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question actually regards two different issues.

The first one is fairly simple to solve and has been already answered : if you want to print only the highest sum, then from your descending sorted result you merely have to print the first item, rather than the whole array.

But the subtle thing is that you want *the latter* of highest sums, if more than one.
And currently you don't work to ensure this: as the JS `Array.prototype.sort()` function is *not stable* you cannot know in which order ex-aequo's will come.

To fix it you must sort not only by sum but also by rank, like this:

```js
function LargestPhoneNumber (array) { 
    
var i = 0,
    phoneNumbers = array.map(function (m) {
    return {
        number: m,
        rank: i++,
        score: m.match(/\d/g).reduce(function (p, c) {
            return +p + +c;
        })
    };
})
phoneNumbers.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.score < b.score) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.score > b.score) {
        return -1;
    }
    // here a.score == b.score, then sort by rank
    if (a.rank < b.rank) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.rank > b.rank) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
console.log(phoneNumbers[0]);

};
LargestPhoneNumber(['555-555-5555','111-111-1111','555-555-5456','222-121-2121']);
```

Anyway since you're only interested by the final result there is another, much more simple, way to achieve it:

```js
function LargestPhoneNumber (numbers) { 
  var selected = '',
      score = 0,
      highestScore = 0;
      
  for (var number of numbers) {
    score = number.match(/\d/g).reduce(function (p, c) {
      return +p + +c;
    });
    
    if (score >= highestScore) {
      highestScore = score;
      selected = number;
    }
  }

  console.log(selected);
}

LargestPhoneNumber(['555-555-5555','111-111-1111','555-555-5456','222-121-2121']);
```

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for your answer and also about the issue concerning to array.prototype.sort(). I'll sort by sum and rank. @cFreed

Comment: Your answers were of great help and properly solved all the issues and doubts I had. Thank you very much! @cFreed

Comment: @g4lvy Glad to help. But, since you say you'll sort by sum and rank, have you seen my edit with a simpler way?

Comment: @g4lvy Huh... just seen your last comment. So don't mind mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is displaying all of them because you asked it to.

```
console.log(sums[0]); //display only the first item in the array
```

Comment: Wow, I see! Thank you! @Draco18s